# Was every (Bayesian) "Prior" once a "Non-Prior"?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, inference

I have always had the following question: **Was every (Bayesian) "Prior" once a "Non-Prior"?**

This seems more like a philosophical question to me, but logically speaking : before something can be considered as prior knowledge, at an earlier point in time - this "prior knowledge" must not have been known, and must have been "directly observed"?

If you takes Bayes' Law for instance:

[image]

In a philosophical sense, could we say the following about Baye's Law?

[image]

In this regard, **Was every (Bayesian) "Prior" once a "Non-Prior"?**

Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed a [philosophical question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/53259).

Answer (score 4):

The question can be re-phrased to “is it possible to have no knowledge at all” and it’s rather a philosophical question that does not fit well for this Q&A site. It boils down to asking if we have any [innate knowledge](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/innate-knowledge) (yes). The prior is formed based on what you know. For example, if you were studying extraterrestrial life forms, your prior would most likely be influenced on what you know about life on Earth. Finally, you can always use extremely vague, weakly informative (“uninformative”) priors.

Comment: @ Tim: Thank you for your answer! I will read this link that you have posted! Just a question: is there any reason that you decided to re-phrase my question and bring it out of the Bayesian context? thank you!

Comment: @stats555 priors are based on knowledge, so it’s the same.

Comment: If I want to fit an bayesian model to a small dataset...  Can I first apply that model to a large dataset and use its output as prior for the small one?
For example I want to fit a regression model to see if smoking has an effect on cancer using 30 observations. And I first apply my model to a public health service database with 1 million observations.